# '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument has type 'int'

Tags: c, error-handling, compiler-errors

I did see a similar question and the solution given was to declare it as char array and not a char. I did that and still see the error.

My code is currently this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
char ticTacToeBoard(char board[11])

{
    printf("%s %s %s %s %s", board[0], board[10], board[1], board[10], board[2]);
}


int main()

{
    char board[11] = {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','__','|'};
    ticTacToeBoard(board);

    return 0;
}
```

The error is in the printf line of the code

Comment: Change `%s` to `%c`. The former is for strings and the latter for a char. The latter is what you have.

Comment: `%s` is expecting a `char *` i.e. a string of characters and you are providing a `char`. Just change `%s` format specifier to `%c`.

Answer (score 1):

the function parameter `board` is a char pointer, so when you try to print an index of that char pointer it gives the dereference of the char in that index.
so what happens is you try to print a string but the variable is a char.
if you want to print the char you'll need the to change the `%s` to a `%c`.
this way you'll print the chars you want from the indexes in the "array" of chars.